# Passing a Function Object and Calling it

Tags: perl, reference

How do I pass a function, `a`, to function, `b`, and have `b` call `a` in Perl?

Answer (score 49):

Here's a complete, working script that demonstrates what you're asking.

```
sub a { print "Hello World!\n"; }

sub b {
    my $func = $_[0];
    $func->();
}

b(\&a);
```

Here's an explanation: you take a reference to function `a` by saying `\&a`.  At that point you have a function reference; while normally a function would be called by saying `func()` you call a function reference by saying `$func->()`

The `->` syntax deal with other references as well.  For example, here's an example of dealing with array and hash references:

```
sub f {
    my ($aref, $href) = @_;
    print "Here's an array reference: $aref->[0]\n";  # prints 5
    print "Here's a hash ref: $href->{hello}\n";      # prints "world"
}

my @a = (5, 6, 7);
my %h = (hello=>"world", goodbye=>"girl");
f(\@a, \%h);
```

Comment: What if I was passing the function as part of a hash, then would it look like this?

$args{function}->();

Comment: I've added examples for array and hash references.

Comment: But what if it was this:
f(function => \&func);

then in the function, f, would it be this?

sub f {
   $args{function}->();
}

Comment: Kys: Yes, '->()' dereferences a code reference and calls it. Arguments to the function go between the parens, as you'd expect.

Comment: function calls follow the same rules as other chained dereferences, so you can discard the arrow and say `$args{function}()`;, but that can be a little confusing.

Comment: What if the `sub a` has arguments?

Comment: @PatrizioRullo: You just pass them the same as you would to any other function, e.g. ``$func->(5, 6)``

Answer (score 10):

You can't pass a function to another function directly. Instead, you pass a *reference* to a function. To call the function you dereference it (as a CODE ref) using `->()`;

```
sub a { print @_ }

sub b {
  my $f = shift;  # assuming that $f is a function reference...
  $f->(@_);       # call it with the remaining arguments
}

b(\&a, "hello, world!");  # prints "hello, world!"
```

Perl doesn't have pass-by-name semantics but you can emulate them using a hash. The method for calling the function is the same. You dereference it.

```
sub a { print @_ }

sub b {
    my %arg = @_;
    $arg{function}->(@{$arg{arguments}});
}

b(function => \&a, arguments => ["hello, world!"]);
```

ObPerl6: Perl 6 will have pass-by-name semantics.

Answer (score 4):

You can access subroutines references as `\&my_method` in Perl, and call those references with `$myref->();`.  Try this:

```
perl -e'sub a { print "foo in a"; }; sub b { shift->(); }; b(\&a);'
```

Good luck!

Comment: What if I was passing the function as part of a hash, then would it look like this? $args{function}->();

Answer (score 4):

Following up to Eli Courtwright's example: If you only use the first function once, you could also call `b` with an anonymous function, like this:

```
b( sub { print "Hello World\n"; } );
```